# Farming isn't effective?

Tags: borderlands-2

Does repeatedly farming a boss give reduced rewards?

I've noticed while running through Terramorphous and The Warrior over and over, the drops are getting worse each time. By worse I mean any color of drops are getting rarer and the total sell value keeps going down as well.

After beating the boss and looting everything I just do a save quit, then continue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem I've killed the bunker 100 times I'm not even joking spent my entire day banging my head on the wall. Just for the sham. If gearbox could make it where on average 20 kills of a certain boss would drop a legendary. Yoteslaya killed doc mercy 4000 times to get the infinity pistol.

Comment: That is not true at least for me, the loot drops are random and after a few runs i even got a legendary shotgun. Social conference call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, there is no such thing as deteriorating drops.

From the dawn of time there were legends of subtle dependencies and rituals, that help a player boost his chances at games like Borderlands. When I was young, I had to convince my friend that shutting down Diablo 2 and restarting it does not boost his loot quality in Baal runs.

Of course, your theory makes more sense than dependencies like that one, but it is still wrong. It is just an unlucky streak and the way humans perceive randomness. Cognition is always working through expectation, and when you come up with a theory, your brain starts picking up evidence of it being true and ignoring conflicting facts.

The only way to check it for sure is to keep a list of every drop, color and price, and look at it when it becomes long enough - say, a hundred runs, but a thousand is better. Any sample less than a hundred would be *random* and would not demonstrate tendencies and chances.

Comment: The way to check it for sure is to look at the code.

Comment: @Fambida Of course! But extensive testing is a next most confident approach, and looking at the code alone should never be sufficient - ask any programmer :)

Comment: I would argue that extensive testing is better than looking at the code anyway.  Just because the code in that one place says X, doesn't mean code elsewhere says Y, or interacts with the code in X to cause unintended behavior :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia

Answer (score 2):

Farming definitely works. I've heard rumors that some bosses give better drops the very first time but I think it's BS; several people have suggested X boss always drops Y legendary the first time, but I've never found this to be true (however I've had Boom and Bewm drop the Bonus Package twice on first runs through different playthroughs).

Particularly with Terramorphous and Bunker I've noticed there seems to be an explicitly set number of green or better, blue or better and purple or better drops. Legendaries are however *much* rarer than they were in Borderlands, so if you're basing your expectations off of BL1, especially Crawmerax's drops, you'll be disapointed. Legendaries drop at their own rate and most are exceedingly rare. I've farmed Warrior maybe 20 times or more and only seen the Conference Call and Impaler once for example.

Sell value is pretty irrelevant in terms of quality. Certain things like rocket shooting Assault Rifles have extremely high prices but aren't particularly better. A white rocket AR sells for more than a purple anything else, generally speaking.

Comment: The first time I've killed warrior on any character or playthrough I get a legendary. I killed warrior today alone maybe 20 times and I got a worthless legendary once from him. I never really farmed any boss in BL1 so I didn't really have expectations luckily. I also noticed that about rocket launchers and snipers are worth tons more. I guess price isn't everything then

Comment: Many games, as old as Diablo 2, feature increased *quest drops*. The same goes with the Warrior - quest kill gives a guaranteed legendary, subsequent kills roll a legendary rarely. Most bosses in Borderlands 2, though, have no special quest drop.

Comment: @OrcJMR I don't think he does though, I've only seen him drop 2 legendaries but I've quest-killed him 4 times though

Comment: Hm. Not my personal experience, I've read it somewhere... Okay, but still a quest drop is much better, even if not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently playing through Borderlands 2 for the fourth time and have yet to see The Warrior drop the first legendary anything.  I farmed him literally 6-8 hours a day for over 2 weeks, at the time it took roughly 10 minutes to kill him and he never dropped a legendary unless it went into the lava.  As far as Terramorphous goes, the only legendary anything it has dropped has been slayer of terramorphous mods.....never anything else.  I have literally had better luck buying legendary weapons in vending machines than getting either of those to drop one.  I have seen chubby varkids drop a crappy launcher, chubby spiderants drop a shield that wasn't worth picking up..other than that, the only items I have seen drop have been slayer of terramorphous and that's all....gearbox really needs to do something about the shoddy drop rates.  I don't mean they should drop some legendary every time, but they should at least have a 5% chance of dropping SOMETHING besides crap items.  And by the way, I cannot play online so getting someone to "dupe" anything for me is out of the question...wouldn't want that anyway, no point in having it if I didn't get it myself